# How to make placeholder still visible?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How to make placeholder always visible?

When i type something into react-select, placeholder vanishes.

I tried to fiddle with custom components, but no success..

Design: [image: where label is placehodler thats is still visible, even if "Hover" in this case value is selected]

Comment: Could you provide a design so we can how would you want the placeholder to still be displayed ? thanks

Comment: Hi @Laura, i've edited post. String "Label" is placehodler, that is still visible even if value string "Hover" is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way I would resolve your problem:

```
const ValueContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return (
    components.ValueContainer && (
      <components.ValueContainer {...props}>
        <div style={{color: 'gray', position: 'absolute', top: 8, left: 8, fontSize: 12}}>Label:</div>
        {children}
      </components.ValueContainer>
    )
  );
};

const styles = {
  singleValue: base => ({
    ...base,
    position: 'relative',
    top: 'initial',
    transform: "none"
  }),
  valueContainer: base => ({
    ...base,
    position: 'relative',
    paddingTop: 20
  })
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        components={{ ValueContainer }}
        placeholder=""
        styles={styles}
        options={options}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see it's a combination of using custom style and components.

First of all I'm killing the `placeholder` and replace it by a `div` inside `ValueContainer` custom component. From there I can style my fake placeholder the way I want and it won't be impacted by the fact the select is filled or not.

Second I'm changing the style to increase the size of the `ValueContainer` and make the possible `SingleValue` `relative` as by default it's `absolute`.

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/joyz6yq7v).

Comment: simple and easy solution. Thanks for that! You saved my lots of work (i was planning to implement custom SingleValue and custom Input (where both have placeholders) but this is much better